# How to install Gym Torcs for Windows

Tags: windows, openai-gym, torcs

I am trying to install [Gym Torcs](https://github.com/ugo-nama-kun/gym_torcs) on my Windows 10 notebook. I was able to install it on the same notebook using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I removed Ubuntu because my notebook had severe overheating issues (also tried Ubuntu 18.04 which was even worse).

The problem is that the authors of Gym Torcs do not provide a documentation (as far as I can see) for installing it on Windows.

I would be glad if someone could give me some hints how I have to adapt the installation on windows. A reference for a tutorial would also help me a lot.

Comment: I think you post your question in a not comfortable place, MathOverflow and Windows support center could help you better.